# Creating a single record from multiple records in SAS

Tags: sas, datastep

I have a SAS Data set called `coaches_assistants` with the following structure. There are always only two records per `TeamID`.

```
TeamID     Team_City    CoachCode
123        Durham       Head_242
123        Durham       Assistant_876
124        London       Head_876
124        London       Assistant_922
125        Bath         Head_667
125        Bath         Assistant_786
126        Dover        Head_544
126        Dover        Assistant_978
...        ...          ....
```

What I'd like to do with this is to create a data set with an extra field called `AssistantCode` and make it look like:

```
TeamID     Team_City    HeadCode   AssistantCode
123        Durham       242        876
124        London       876        922
125        Bath         667        786
126        Dover        544        978
...        ...          ...        ...
```

If possible, I'd like to do this in a single DATA step (though I recognize that I might need a PROC SORT step first). I know how to do it in python or ruby or any traditional scripting languages, but I don't know how to do it in SAS.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions (one using a data step as requested and another using PROC SQL):

```
data have;
   length TeamID $3 Team_City CoachCode $20; 
   input TeamID $ Team_City $ CoachCode $;
   datalines;
123        Durham       Head_242
123        Durham       Assistant_876
124        London       Head_876
124        London       Assistant_922
125        Bath         Head_667
125        Bath         Assistant_786
126        Dover        Head_544
126        Dover        Assistant_978
run;

/* A data step solution */
proc sort data=have;
   by TeamID;
run;

data want1(keep=TeamID Team_City HeadCode AssistantCode);
   /* Define all variables, retain the new ones */
   length TeamID $3 Team_City $20 HeadCode $3 AssistantCode $3; 
   retain HeadCode AssistantCode; 
   set have;
      by TeamID;
   if CoachCode =: 'Head'
      then HeadCode = substr(CoachCode,6,3);
      else AssistantCode = substr(CoachCode,11,3);
   if last.TeamID;
run;

/* An SQL solution */
proc sql noprint;
   create table want2 as
   select TeamID
        , max(Team_City) as Team_City
        , max(CASE WHEN CoachCode LIKE 'Head%'
                   THEN substr(CoachCode,6,3) ELSE ' '
              END) LENGTH=3 as HeadCode
        , max(CASE WHEN CoachCode LIKE 'Assistant%'
                   THEN substr(CoachCode,11,3) ELSE ' '
              END) LENGTH=3 as AssistantCode
   from have
   group by TeamID;
quit;
```

PROC SQL has the advantage of not requiring you to sort the data in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I went with the first approach and it worked like a charm. I haven't yet delved into SAS SQL, so I'll look at it later when I get the chance.

Comment: When you use a `BY` statement in data step processing, special variables are automatically created to assist processing.  Two "dot" variables are created for each variable listed in the statement: `FIRST.variable` and `LAST.variable`, which identify the relative position of an obs within a group. `if LAST.TeamID;` is a "subsetting-IF" statement used to only output one obs per TeamID.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't know about `FIRST` and `LAST`.

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible to do in one datastep, I generally find that this sort of problem is better served in PROC TRANSPOSE.  Less manual coding this way and more flexibility for new things (say a new value "HeadAssistant" appeared, this would instantly work).

```
data have;
length coachcode $25;
input TeamID     Team_City  $  CoachCode $;
datalines;
123        Durham       Head_242
123        Durham       Assistant_876
124        London       Head_876
124        London       Assistant_922
125        Bath         Head_667
125        Bath         Assistant_786
126        Dover        Head_544
126        Dover        Assistant_978
;;;;
run;

data have_t;
set have;
id=scan(coachcode,1,'_');
val = scan(coachcode,2,'_');
keep teamId team_city id val;
run;

proc transpose data=have_t out=want(drop=_name_);
by teamID team_city;
id id;
var val;
run;
```

Comment: I like how clean this looks, but when I tried to run it with my data set (with 120,000+ observations), the `want` table was created without any columns for some reason. I'll try it again later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you've sorted the data by `teamID`, and head coaches always come before assistants. Caveat: untested (I really need to get access to SAS again....)

```
data want (drop=nc coachcode);
    set have;
    length headcode assistantcode $3;
    retain headcode;
    by teamid;
    nc = length(coachcode);
    if substr(coachcode, 1, 4) = 'Head' then
        headcode = substr(coachcode, nc-2, nc);
    else
        assistantcode = substr(coachcode, nc-2, nc);
    if last.teamid;
run;
```

Comment: SCAN is probably better than substring for this :)

Comment: @Joe Thanks, forgot about that one.